# Помогите довести до ума регулярку

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте Друзья! Пишу шаблонизатор для своей системы, в документах будут метки, я их назвал **микротегами** и имеют они вид :

```
{multylang owner="goods" placeholder="good_description"}
```

разбираю следующий документ :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>{multylang owner="html" placeholder="document.general_title"} - {html owner="html" placeholder="title"}</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./system/script.js"></script>

<link href="./system/templates/default_2/default_2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

{html owner="html" placeholder="head"}

</head>

<body>

<div id="general_content">

{html owner="html" placeholder="content"}{html owner="html" placeholder="after_content"}

</div><!--general_content-->

</body>
</html>
```

Регулярки знаю плохо, поэтому написал вот такую :

```
preg_match_all('#\{(\w{2,})\ (\w{2,})\=\"(.*)\"\ {0,}\}#iu', $strtp, $microtags);
```

Моя регулярка неправильно разбирает строки типа :

```
{html owner="html" placeholder="content"}{html owner="html" placeholder="after_content"}
```

**Подскажите пожалуйста правильную регулярку, учитывая** :

1. {multylang - длиной минимум два символа(a-Z0-9_), нужно сохранить(без скобочки)
2. поле="значение" - таких записей может быть сколько угодно, но не менее 1
3. поле="значение" - **поле** длиной минимум два символа(a-Z0-9_), **значение** может быть пустым

**Поле** и **значение** желательно записать в разные массивы

Зачем мне этот велосипед? Зная своего начальника, я готов с 90% точностью предсказать то, что в дальнейшем это сэкономит мне нервы и время.

Comment: А что вам мешает использовать самые обычные теги с атрибутами? Ну, то есть, не "обычные" теги, а уникальные для вашего шаблонизатора и не пересекающиеся со стандартными. Например: `<multylang owner="html" placeholder="document.general_title" />`, или `<my_html owner="html" placeholder="content" />`. Тогда и парсинг станет намного проще, и не так глюко-дыряво-коряв, как регекспы.

Comment: Дело в том, что имена уникальными могут и не быть(приставка my и т.д. тоже не вариант), и тут начнутся проблемы, а также будет идти проверка, нужно будет узнать - присутствуют ли микротеги в документе/файле/просто в строке, плюс мне все же не хотелось чтобы эти теги смешивались с HTML-тегами.

Comment: У Вас вложенность предусмотрена: `{html owner="html" placeholder="{html owner="html" placeholder="after_content"}"}`? Меня интресует, допустимо ли в атрибутах наличие символа фигурной скобки `{`?

Comment: romeo, нет, такого не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$input = '{html owner="html" placeholder="content"}{html owner="html" placeholder="after_content"}';

$callback = function($matches){
    echo "Tag name: {$matches['name']}\n";
    if (preg_match_all('#(?P<attributes>[\w-]+)\s*=\s*"(?P<values>[^\"]+)"#iu', $matches['attributes'], $attributes)) {
        var_dump(array_combine($attributes['attributes'], $attributes['values']));
    }
};

preg_replace_callback(
    '#{
        (?P<name>[\w-]+)\s+
        (?P<attributes>[^{}]+)\s*
      }
    #iux',
    $callback,
    $input
);
```

[**Смотрите результат**](http://ideone.com/4Y5d1C)

Думаю, дальше сами разберётесь.

Comment: Всё супер, спасибо большое!